# MailKit Pop3 Read All Messages Issue

Tags: c#, pop3, mailkit

I'm using mailkit to receive emails. Now I use pop3 protocol and when the code run first I can get all message. But later I can receive just new mails.

I use this code:

```
using (var client = new Pop3Client ()) {
    client.Connect ("pop.friends.com", 110, false);

    // Note: since we don't have an OAuth2 token, disable
    // the XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.
    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove ("XOAUTH2");

    client.Authenticate ("joey", "password");

    for (int i = 0; i < client.Count; i++) {
        var message = client.GetMessage (i);
        Console.WriteLine ("Subject: {0}", message.Subject);
    }

    client.Disconnect (true);
}
```

I want to see all messages and all time, not just first time. Is there anyway to do it with mailkit?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your POP3 server is at gmail.com, then this is a GMail configuration issue that you need to fix by going into your GMail Settings and setting it up to be able to see all mail and not just mail that hasn't been seen.

You can find more information in MailKit's [FAQ](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#GMailHiddenMessages).